# In Dart Angular, how to pass functions to component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component MyComp and I would like to pass a function to it as parameter.
More precisely I would like to do something like that:

**dart component file:**

```dart
 @NgComponent(
        selector: 'mycomp',
        publishAs: 'ctrl',
        map: const {
          'myfunc' :'=> myfunc'
        }
    )
class MyComponent {
   Function myfunc;

   ....
   myfunc();
}
```

**html:**

```html
<mycomp myfunc="ctrl.myfunc"></button-list>
```

The problem is that myfunc is null in the component.
Do I miss something? How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use '&' to bind a function to a field:

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'mycomp',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'myfunc' :'&myfunc'
    }
)
class MyComponent {
    Function myfunc;

   ....
   myfunc();
}
```

http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/NgComponent.html#map

Comment: Great. To pass parameter, it there something simpler than myfunc({'\$myparam': xyz} with the html being <mycomp myfunc='ctrl.func($myparam)'>  ?

Comment: Hmm, do you want to pass a parameter to mycomp when binding the function or from mycomp when calling myfunc?

Comment: I want to pass a parameter when calling myfunc.

Comment: Just call it like any other function. When binding it, in the html just write <mycomp myfunc='ctrl.func'>. Hint: '$' in identifiers is reserved for angular-specific members.

Comment: To pass parameters you'll need to pass a `locals` scope when calling the function: `myfunc({'param1': paramVal1, 'param2': paramVal2});` and when binding `<mycomp myfunc='ctrl.myfunc(param1, param2)'>`

Comment: When calling the function you need to use <mycomp myfunc='ctrl.func()'>

Comment: ...and parameters need to be maps

Answer (score 6):

The preferred way in AngularDart is to use annotations

```dart
@NgCallback('myfunc') Function myFunc;
```