# What is the annotation equivalent of map: const {'foo':'&foo'} in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I see that [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20443612/123471) shows how to bind to a field that contains a function:

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'mycomp',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'myfunc' :'&myfunc'
    }
)
class MyComponent {
    Function myfunc;
```

However, it is recommended to use annotations to declare what fields are bound, and how. I see `@NgOneWay` (`=>`) and others, but I don't see an annotation for `&myfunc`.

What annotation should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just saw you created a new question for this one:

For callbacks `&` use [`@NgCallback`](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/NgCallback.html)